# Frame Capture in external file Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, file, rgb, capture

I captured a frame using `capture()` function in *Matlab*, However it returns a black image with a small area of captured whole image, I dont know why this is happening. I want to do this in every 5th *iteration* of *loop*.
I want to store that image in file, what *syntax* should I follow in order to check the image in file.
Further more, what are the suggestions for capturing frames in Matlab and save them in file for later estimation?
EDIT1: My code is working perfect now, but not capturing the frame, a black image instead.
**My Code:**

```
w = vrworld('myworld');
open(w);
c = vr.canvas(w, gcf, [30 30 300 200]);
z=capture(c);
image(z);
 savename = [...
    'C:\Users\My-PC\Documents\MATLAB\Project\image_', ...
    num2str(1), '.jpg']; 
imwrite(z, savename);
```

Comment: Never seen `capture`.  Try `z = frame2im(getframe(fig));` instead.

Comment: OK, I'm talking about this by the way. http://www.mathworks.com/help/sl3d/vr.canvascapture.html

Comment: @chappjc please check the edit1 of my post.